# Zend Server Job predecessor fails dependent

Tags: php

I using Zend Server Jobs with setting max concurrent jobs = 4, this setting is needed - many high priority jobs what need to serve ASAP.

Also I have jobs with low priority with long execution time 5-7 min - heavy DB operation - and I want this jobs run one at the time - if run parallel compete for DB resources and timeouts. I have loop that creates them ( about 30 jobs ), I am checking if jobs with proper name existing in queue using getJobsList(), pickup biggest job id and set as predecessor to next job. However even job was already created (second iteration) is not picked up by getJobsList(), and following iterations do not picked up biggest / newest job id...

**Is it delay is involved during job creation ?** createHttpJob() and following getJobsList() does not return recently created...

After predecessor is set and predecessor fails - like timeout - it automatically fails dependents.

**Is it a way to set predecessor only to complete regardless of status** - just not being in queue or already running ?.

Comment: Are you talking about the [Zend Server Job Queue](http://www.zend.com/en/products/server/zend-server-job-queue)?  Zend Server has nothing to do with Zend Framework.

Comment: Yes Zend Server Job Queue - there is nothing about Zend Framework in my post...

Comment: So why did you tag it [tag:zend-framework]?

Comment: The [tag:zend] tag is aliased to [tag:zend-framework] due to terminology abuse.

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to figure out your problem and it takes me to a problem which I fixed some time back, I am sharing my problem/solution here so that you can get some way out from your problem assuming that you will be able to better solve your problem with some hints from it.

I had a considerably simple problem where I had a table of messages which I have to post (so that their status gets updated from Pending to Sent or Error). Now having single JOB running and doing all this sending created problem and so I have to spawn multiple instances which I did by crontab which starts every 5 seconds (for this I have to write sleep logic because cron by default starts every minute only). Now each job is schedule to start at the interval of 5 seconds and have specific JOB-WORKER-ID which is assigned manually as argument to the script because I wanted ID for each job so at the same time there is no duplicate JOB-WORKER-ID active.

For that I have kept a table like JOB_LOG, which logs all jobs and stores it's start_time, end_time and # of messages sent during execution of each job. Now every time I start new JOB I check whether same JOB-WORKER-ID is running or not? by firing following query to JOB_LOG table.

```
SELECT end_time FROM JOB_LOG WHERE job_worker_id = <N> ORDER BY JOB_LOG_ID DESC
```

If end_time is not specified it means that JOB is still running else it is safe to start new JOB. :-)

Table structure for the table would be something similar to below:

```
job_log
 - job_log_id
 - start_time
 - end_time
 - message_sent_count
 - job_worker_id
```

I know that my answer does not exactly solve your problem but I see that there are some similarities and you can find some clues from within.

Good luck.